# express session - reading req.session in multiple files

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, fetch-api

I have a server.js file where I load all files with api requests

```
const API_PORT = 5000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const postUserLogin = require('./routes/POST/userLogin');
const getUserData = require('./routes/GET/userData');
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const cors = require('cors');

require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", postUserLogin);
app.use("/", getUserData);

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT} ...`));

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log("Connect with database"))
    .catch(error => console.error("Connect failed...", error));
```

In the userLogin file I store the user id in req.session.userID

```
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require('joi');
const model = require('../../models/userRegistration');
const modelUserData = require('../../models/userData');
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");


function validate(data) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string(),
        password: Joi.string()
    });

    return schema.validate(data, { presence: "required" });
}

/**
 * Function for verify login password
 * @param {string} passwordHash Hash password from database
 * @param {string} password 
 * @returns boolean
 */
function verifyPassword(passwordHash, password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash);
}

app.post("/api/auth", (req, res) => {
    const loginData = req.body;
    const {error} = validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        return;
    }
    model.findOne({email: loginData.email})
        .then(user => {
            if (!user || !verifyPassword(user.passwordHash, loginData.password)) {
                res.send({"verify" : -1, "msg" : "Invalid login details"});
                return;
            }
            const sessionUser = user.toObject();
            delete sessionUser.passwordHash;
            req.session.user = sessionUser;
            req.session.userID = sessionUser._id;
            req.session.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send({"verify" : -1, "msg" : "There was an error when logging in"});
                    return;
                }
                res.send({"verify" : 1})
            });
        })
        .catch(() => res.status(500).send({"verify" : -1, "msg" : "An error occurred while searching for a user"}));
});

module.exports = app;
```

In the userData.js file I want to read data from req.sessios.userID, but I get the value undefined.

```
const express = require('express');
const model = require('../../models/userData');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: "secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    httpOnly: true
  }
}));

app.get('/api/userData', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.session.userID;
  model.findOne({userID: id})
    .then(user => {
      res.send(user);
    })
    .catch(() => {res.status(404).send("Failed to retrieve any data from the database")})
});

module.exports = app;
```

In React I first send a fetch request to /api/auth and then to /api/userData, but the variable is still undefined.

Does anyone know how I can access the req.session.userID value?

I've tried looking here for answers and asking and chatGPT :D and still no result for me.

Comment: To start with, it appears you're creating more than one `app` object.  You only want to create one per application and then share that with other modules via import/export.  Or create routers in the other files and export those routers to the main file so it can be hooked up to the existing `app` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand creating multiple application objects.

Comment: Don't create multiple app objects.  Create one app object in your main file where you start the server.  Then create and export router objects in the other files.

Comment: If `.req.session` is `undefined`, then your order of routes is wrong and your route handler is getting called before the session has been set up.  If `req.session` is valid, but `req.session.userID` is `undefined`, then either you never saved the `userID` properly into the session in the first place or you are losing the session cookie in the client or not sending the session cookie with the client request.